# JQuery TextBox limit number onchange checks only first number

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, textbox, onchange

I am working on a simple shopping cart application. (Asp.Net MVC5)
I get product properties when you click the product inside a ListBox. A simple table shows productPrice and currentStock with Jquery and ajax.
Then I want to prevent user to enter quantity bigger than currentStock quantity.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtQuantity",
onkeyup = "calculateTotal()", onchange = "calculateTotal()"} })
```

js code:

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var v = $('#txtQuantity').val();
    var stockQuantity = $('#lblStock').text();//This is where I get the current stock
    if (v > stockQuantity) {
        $('#txtQuantity').val(stockQuantity);
    }
    var reTotal = $('#lblPrice').text() * $('#txtQuantity').val();
    $('#lblTotal').text(reTotal);
    };
```

This code works if you enter a bigger number than currentquantity.

For example:

currentQuantity= 7,

When you enter 8 or 9. It changes to 7. But when you enter 65, 45, 1000 it does nothing. Because the first character of number is less than 7.

How can I check whole number?

P.S I can do this with [Remote] on model validation. But I just want to use this method.

Comment: Add **+** in front of `$('#txtQuantity').val();`, it'll cast the string to number, same goes for other too

Comment: Or use `var v = Number($('#txtQuantity').val());` and `var stockQuantity = Number($('#lblStock').text());`

Comment: You are fantastic. Thank you! `var v = +$('#txtQuantity').val();` and `var stockQuantity = +$('#lblStock').text();` works perfectly